# How can show conditions from the same table without writing SQL in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

[Here is the live demo](http://code.runnable.com/VwZ0xWvFwzBdthDT/checkboxes-parent-and-childs-for-ruby-on-rails)

**Tables:**

```
|perfils|
  |id|  |name|
    1     Administrator
    2     Admin for products

|grants|
  |id|  |parent_id|  |name|
   1        0       Module Clients  #parent
   2        1         Show Client   ###child from Module Clients
   3        1         New Client    ###child = Module Clients
   4        1         Edit Client   ###child = Module Clients 
   5        0       Module Products #parent
   6        5         Show Product  ###child = Module Products
   7        5         New Product   ###child = Module Products

|perfil_accesses|
  |id|  |grant_id| |perfil_id|
   1       1           1
   2       2           1
   3       3           1
```

**Controller perfil_controller.rb:**

```
def new
  @perfil.new
  @grants = Grant.where(parent_id: 0)
end

def create
  @perfil = Perfil.new(perfil_params)
  if @perfil.save
    @accesses.each do |access|
      if params["access_"+access.id.to_s] == "on"
        perfil_access = Grant.new()
        perfil_access.access_id = access.id
        perfil_access.perfil_id = @perfil.id
        perfil_access.save
      end
    end

    redirect_to perfils_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

**Models**

```
#Perfil.rb
  has_many :perfil_accesses

#PerfilAccess.rb
  belongs_to :grant 
  belongs_to :perfil
```

**View new.html.erb**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).on('change', '.parentCheckBox', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.closest('div').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', that.is(':checked'));
 $(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0);  
 });

 $(document).on('change', '.childCheckBox', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var par = that.closest('ul');
  var c = par.find('.childCheckBox').filter(':checked').length;
  var parChk = par.closest('div').parent().find('.parentCheckBox');
  var checked = c > 0;

  $(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0); 
  parChk.prop('checked', checked);
  console.log(checked);
});
</script>


<%= form_for(@perfil) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :name %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>

 <% @grants.each do |access| %>
 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> <%= grant.name %>
   <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_<%= access.id %>').style.display='';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/plus_add_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a>
   <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_<%= access.id %>').style.display='none';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/minus_remove_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a>
   <br/>

   <div id="div_<%= access.id %>" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
    <% Grant.where(parent_id: access.id ).each do |grant|%>
       <li><input id="access_<%= grant.id %>" name="access_<%= grant.id %>" type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /><%= grant.name %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>    
 <% end %>

 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the problem:
Is there a solution to show rows childs from parents without writing SQL text in the view?

```
<% Grant.where(parent_id: access.id ).each do |grant|%>
  <li><input id="access_<%= grant.id %>" name="access_<%= grant.id %>" type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" /><%= grant.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

I tried:

```
#CONTROLLER
  @grants = []
  @accesses.each do |access|
     @grants << Access.where(parent_id: access.id)
  end

#VIEW 
 <% @accesses.each do |access| %>
    <%= access.name %>

    <% access.where(parent_id: access.id).each do |grant|
    <ul>
      <li><%= grant.name %></li>
    </ul> 
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have a relation on grants, a belongs_to accesses?

Comment: yes i have that, I updated the post and wrote models.

Comment: I'm doing a query from  the same table not from relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are appending the `@grants` rather than making a nested variable.  The best way to address this is to create a hash that relates the grants to the access.

```
 @accesses.each do |access|
   @grants << Access.where(parent_id: access.id)
 end
```

The `@accesses` variable should be able to contain parent related to children in a nested hash so that:

```
@accesses[0] = {   parent: Grant.where(parent_id: 0).first,
                 children: Grant.where(parent_id: Grant.where(parent_id:0).first.id }
```

In the view this could be used like:

```
<% @accesses.each do |access| %>
  <%= access[:parent].id %>
  <% access[:children].each do |grant|
    <%= grant.id %>
```

to get this to work in the controller, the following query would be used:

```
@accesses = Grant.where(parent_id: 0).map do |access|
  { parent: access, children: Grant.where(parent_id: access.id) }
```

I think you were indicating that the grant table holds parents(access) and children(grants)

Comment: Fantastic. This worked and how did you get this information? or examples? need to practice this.